# HTTP requests: golang with graphQL?

Tags: go, graphql, dgraph

We are using slash graphql and I can write basic queries like:

```
query{
    queryUser{
      user{
         username}
      }
}

jsonData := `{
        query: 
            { 
                queryUser {
                    username
                }
            }
    }`

request, err := http.NewRequest("POST", "https://<GRAPHQL_API_HERE>", []byte(jsonData))
```

But I dont know how to write this kind of query.

```
mutation addAuthor($author: [AddAuthorInput!]!) {
  addAuthor(input: $author) {
    author {
      id
      name
    }
  }
}
```

Any help is appreciated?

Comment: Just a quick note here: your `jsonData` variable does not actually contain JSON.

Answer (score 2):

You can use this package **github.com/machinebox/graphql**. Just provide your query in string.

```
// create a client (safe to share across requests)
client := graphql.NewClient("https://<GRAPHQL_API_HERE>")

// make a request
req := graphql.NewRequest(`
    query ($key: String!) {
        items (id:$key) {
            field1
            field2
            field3
        }
    }
`)

// set any variables
req.Var("key", "value")

// run it and capture the response
var respData ResponseStruct
if err := client.Run(ctx, req, &respData); err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}
```

[Note] Code borrowed from documentation.

For your case request must be

```
req := graphql.NewRequest(fmt.Sprintf(`
mutation addAuthor($author: [%s!]!) {
  addAuthor(input: $author) {
    author {
      id
      name
     }
    }
   }
 `,stringAuthorInput))
```

Comment: stringAuthorInput.......i want struct to be converted into this input. but golang converts struct name to string. How can we avoid it?  I want this: {name: "fsdfd"} and golang marshals object to this: {"name": "fasfsd"}. Latter does not work.

Comment: You can build a method that returns a required string from a given struct. Won’t that solve your problem.

Comment: I need something more intuitive. Finally using net/http and passing everything(struct) in http request body.